# Medspacy colab install

Tags: spacy

Can anyone get medspacy to work on colab?  I have tried reinstall of python 3.8 but no dice.  I have tried installing medspacy via pip

Traceback (most recent call last)

in

```
  1 import spacy
```

----> 2 import medspacy

```
  3 from spacy.tokens import Span

  4 from medspacy.sentence_splitting import PyRuSHSentencizer

  5 from medspacy.section_detection import Sectionizer
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'medspacy'

---

NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can

manually installCan anyone get medspacy to work on colab?  I have tried reinstall of python 3.8 but no dice.  I have tried installing medspacy via pip

low.

Can anyone get medspacy to work on colab?  I have tried reinstall of python 3.8 but no dice.  I have tried installing medspacy via pip.

Answer (score 0):

If you pip install `medspacy` it will work in Google Colab, see the code block from medspacy's [GitHub README](https://github.com/medspacy/medspacy) below:

```
import medspacy
from medspacy.ner import TargetRule
from medspacy.visualization import visualize_ent

# Load medspacy model
nlp = medspacy.load()
print(nlp.pipe_names)

text = """
Past Medical History:
1. Atrial fibrillation
2. Type II Diabetes Mellitus

Assessment and Plan:
There is no evidence of pneumonia. Continue warfarin for Afib. Follow up for management of type 2 DM.
"""

# Add rules for target concept extraction
target_matcher = nlp.get_pipe("medspacy_target_matcher")
target_rules = [
    TargetRule("atrial fibrillation", "PROBLEM"),
    TargetRule("atrial fibrillation", "PROBLEM", pattern=[{"LOWER": "afib"}]),
    TargetRule("pneumonia", "PROBLEM"),
    TargetRule("Type II Diabetes Mellitus", "PROBLEM", 
              pattern=[
                  {"LOWER": "type"},
                  {"LOWER": {"IN": ["2", "ii", "two"]}},
                  {"LOWER": {"IN": ["dm", "diabetes"]}},
                  {"LOWER": "mellitus", "OP": "?"}
              ]),
    TargetRule("warfarin", "MEDICATION")
]
target_matcher.add(target_rules)

doc = nlp(text)
visualize_ent(doc)
```

Output:

[image]